# iOS Salesforce Mobile SDK Native Swift - can we change Logout Behaviour?

Tags: ios, sdk

I am using all the latest and greatest : XCode 13.2.1, Salesforce Mobile SDK 10.

I am writing a native iOS Swift app and I wish to DEFER the Salesforce login to a point in the application that makes sense. (Perhaps the user doesn't even want to connect to Salesforce :) )

It's all very easy. I simply defer the call to AuthHelper.loginIfRequired() to wherever it makes sense for me.

OK, very good.

Now I want the same ability if the user logs off yes? I do NOT want the Login Page in my face just because they log off. I want to decide what happens.

Hmmmm?? I call **UserAccountManager.shared.logout**() to logout (***please correct me if that is the wrong thing to do***). It appears (from the logs) to do what I think it should do, and the **handleLogout**() method of **AuthHelper** is invoked (not by me of course, by the SDK).
The code (in **handleLogout**()) tries to help?? and decides that if there are no current active users left, ***then it will call AuthHelper.loginIfRequired() on my behalf :(***
OK, that's pretty solid logic, if that's what I want, but I don't!! :) I want to control if/when the login flow should be initiated.

I can't figure out how to do it :(

I can of course register call backs for 'forLogoutNotifications' and all that jazz works, but I cannot stop the call to the existing AuthHelper.handleLogout() method from executing. I want my own version :)

Yes, I'm an iOS newbie, and perhaps there is a simple answer, but I don't get it :(
You can see the 'problem child' line of code (in the SDK AuthHelper) at the bottom there :(

Thanks in advance for any iOS dudes helping me!!

```
+ (void)handleLogout:(UIScene *)scene completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock {
    // Multi-user pattern:
    // - If there are two or more existing accounts after logout, let the user choose the account
    //   to switch to.
    // - If there is one existing account, automatically switch to that account.
    // - If there are no further authenticated accounts, present the login screen.
    //
    // Alternatively, you could just go straight to re-initializing your app state, if you know
    // your app does not support multiple accounts.  The logic below will work either way.
    NSArray *allAccounts = [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].allUserAccounts;
    if ([allAccounts count] > 1) {
        SFDefaultUserManagementViewController *userSwitchVc = [[SFDefaultUserManagementViewController alloc] initWithCompletionBlock:^(SFUserManagementAction action) {
            [[[SFSDKWindowManager sharedManager] mainWindow:scene].window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        }];
        [[[SFSDKWindowManager sharedManager] mainWindow:scene].window.rootViewController presentViewController:userSwitchVc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    } else {
        if ([allAccounts count] == 1) {
            [[SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance] switchToUser:([SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].allUserAccounts)[0]];
            if (completionBlock) {
                completionBlock();
            }
        } else {
            [self loginIfRequired:scene completion:completionBlock];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **forceioscreate** wizard thingee will generate code in the **SceneDelegate** that looks like this :

```
AuthHelper.registerBlock(forCurrentUserChangeNotifications: scene) {
            self.resetViewState {
                self.setupRootViewController()
            }
        }
```

So they're using **AuthHelper** to register a block of code to be run whenever a User Change Notification is received. OK, fair enough ...

Let's look at that code (in **AuthHelper**) for a bit (hope the image is clear enough)

#124 is where we end up as a result of the call from the SceneDelegate. In this function (on #125) it **registerForLogoutNotifications**.

Well, OK I guess. A logout is a change I suppose, so I'll give them that.

But what does registering for LogoutNotifications do exactly (#135)?

Well, it adds an observer for the logout (event), and when it receives one, it actually executes **it's OWN**  '*handleLogout() function*' (#137)
That is the function that has the logic that will eventually call the **loginIfRequired**() function.

No mate. I don't want that at all!!!

For logout scenarios I want a pattern similar to what you see at the bottom there (handling switchUser scenarios). There it is doing what I asked and that is to run the completion block that 'I' supply when this notification is received.

[image]

Either I'm missing something very basic (quite possible as I am a newb), or this **AuthHelper** thing cannot help me at all.
The only way I can NOT run the handleLogout() is to not use AuthHandler at all. So, yes, I'm questioning my stupidity or the design of this helper (or both) !!!!

My solution :
I don't (can't) use AuthHelper, so I do it myself like so :

[image]

There is a lot of cool stuff in the SDK and obviously a lot of work has been put into it, but for me at least, documentation is sorely lacking (just my opinion) (or perhaps I really am an idiot :( )

anyway, perhaps someone can find some of this useful.... or not .....